# Eigenvalues of symmetric tridiagonal matrices with identical off diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, tridiagonal-matrices

Is there a simple analytical solution to obtain eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) for this type of tridiagonal matrices ? ( Off diagonal elements are identical and the matrix is symmetric)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}-k & k & 0 & 0   \\\ 
k & a_{2}-2\cdot k & k &  0 \\\
0 & k & -a_{2}-2\cdot k & k  \\\ 
0 & 0 & k & -a_{1}-k
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To obtain eigenvalues of symmetric tridiagonal matrices, I used the formula 
$$
P_{k} (\lambda)=(\alpha_{k}−\lambda)P_{k-1}(\lambda)−\beta^2_{k-1}P_{k-2}(\lambda),
$$ 
but I could not find any simplification.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: No (I'm assuming you mean in general, not just for $n=4$). We're essentially dealing with the discrete Schrodinger equation $y_{n+1}+y_{n-1}+b_n y_n = \lambda y_n$, which can't be solved explicitly in general.

Comment: @Christian. n>4 would be better. But if a solution exists for n=4, I will be satisfied. There is also another constraint that I did not mention. a1=3*a2. I do not know if it could help. And yes, it is related to the discrete Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @Stef1611: For $n=4$ the characteristic polynomial has degree $4$, so there's a formula for the zeros (though it probably won't be pretty).

Comment: @Christian. I agree, they are not pretty at all. I used sympy to calculate them.